# Group more than one value from specific attributes of an object

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a little doubt here.

I have a list of a specific object and would like to group the similar data.

Currently my code snippet looks like this:

Important -> This is my populated list **PreencherDados.listarAlunos()**

```
    Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Aluno>>> map = PreencherDados.listarAlunos()
            .stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Aluno::getNome,
                            Collectors.groupingBy(Aluno::getBimestre))
            );

    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, List<Aluno>>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(" NOME: " + entry.getKey() + " || BIMESTRE: " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

**This is the current result:**

NOME: JOAO || BIMESTRE: {1=[entidade.Aluno@50], 2=[entidade.Aluno@24, entidade.Aluno@44], 3=[entidade.Aluno@2f, entidade.Aluno@476, entidade.Aluno@476, entidade.Aluno@476], 4=[entidade.Aluno@22, entidade.Aluno@32]}

NOME: ANA || BIMESTRE: {1=[entidade.Aluno@9a], 2=[entidade.Aluno@c7], 3=[entidade.Aluno@45, entidade.Aluno@246, entidade.Aluno@4f]}

NOME: PEDRO || BIMESTRE: {1=[entidade.Aluno@21, entidade.Aluno@18d], 2=[entidade.Aluno@23, entidade.Aluno@5a, entidade.Aluno@68, entidade.Aluno@48, entidade.Aluno@ac], 3=[entidade.Aluno@26, entidade.Aluno@476], 4=[entidade.Aluno@5c, entidade.Aluno@df]}

NOME: MARIA || BIMESTRE: {3=[entidade.Aluno@20, entidade.Aluno@476, entidade.Aluno@476, entidade.Aluno@476], 4=[entidade.Aluno@25, entidade.Aluno@2b, entidade.Aluno@7a, entidade.Aluno@ca]}

**The result I would like to get is:**

NOME: JOAO || BIMESTRE: 1=1, 2=2, 3=4, 4=2

NOME: ANA || BIMESTRE: 1=1, 2=1, 3=3

NOME: PEDRO || BIMESTRE: 1=2, 2=5, 3=2, 4=2

NOME: MARIA || BIMESTRE: 3=4, 4=4

If you look closely, I would like to transform the objects on the list into a sum of themselves.

I don't know if I'm doing it right, so I would like your help! Thank you very much

Comment: For NOME: JOAO, should it be 3=4?

Comment: Yes Gryphon!! i will correct this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(" NOME: " + entry.getKey() + " || BIMESTRE: " +
                    entry.getValue().entrySet().stream().map( e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue().size() ).collect(
                            Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Comment: my god @Gryphon, your response was really quick, and it got what I wanted.

Thank you!

Comment: glad it helps you!